# Trying to fix MISRA Violation Rule 10.4: unsigned 32-bit int and signed 32-bit int, which do not match

Tags: c, misra

```
#define INIT_VALUE 1u
typedef unsigned int uint32_t; 
typedef signed int int32_t;
void do_test(uint32_t var1, int32_t var2);

void do_test(uint32_t var1, int32_t var2) 
{  uint32_t m_var = INIT_VALUE;
   m_var = (m_var << 1) + (var1 + var2);
}
```

This code resulted in violation of Rule 10.4 which is due to unsigned var1 and signed var2.

I have tried in casting one of the variable to other. But that is not a generic way.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: The `do_test()` function is pretty useless at all. It does effectively nothing, and will be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: I did that to avoid other  misra rule violations

Comment: It the goal to add a `uint32_t` and a `int32_t` and test if the sum is in `uint32_t` range?

Comment: @Suraj Please at least cite the rule. Misra is a closed standard, and not everyone has bought one of their costly copies of the rules refernce. And even if so, not everyone will remember without additional efforts, what exactly _"Rule 10.4"_ said.

Comment: @user0042 £10 is hardly a "costly" standard. Try buying an ISO standard.

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335074/misra-violation-rule-10-4-unsigned-32-bit-int-and-signed-32-bit-int-which-do-no.

Answer (score 1):

Rule 10.4 is a sound one, as it prevents implicit type conversions that can lead to a change of signedness. This is what is happening in your code, `var1 + var2` leads to `var2` getting silently promoted to an unsigned type. This is not good, since there must be a reason why this variable was signed in the first place.

Simply make sure that you keep track of signedness in your algorithm. If the signed variable will have a negative value, then an implicit conversion to unsigned is a bug. Or otherwise, if you know that the value is always positive and therefore signedness does not matter, then simply cast the signed variable to `uint32_t`.

Comment: However, since the OP says that the purpose of this function is to dodge some other MISRA warning, I suspect that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are probably better ways to solve the root cause of the warnings.